# Field Type Checking for annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I am working on annotations and I need to have compiler time error when below code is encountered

```
public void myMethod(@myAnn Object[] ob) {
.
.
}
```

Compiler error should not be thrown with below code

```
public void myMethod(@myAnn Object ob) {
.
.
}
```

i want type should be `Object` and not `Object[]`

I believe this is  kind of type checking.Is there a way i can achieve this..reading at some other posts and JSR's i came to know this is something which is not allowed for annotations(I might be wrong hence i posted this q).

Answer (score 0):

check for annotation type and make sure it's `Object.class`

like below code

```
if (annotation.annotationType().equals(java.lang.Object.class)){}
```

Comment: hi,i believe the above code works at runtime ,,but is there a way i can have a check at compile time??The reason i am asking is doing the processing at runtime  is causing a considerable overhead(around 4%) which i feel can be avoided if a check is present at compile time.Thanks for your reply.